# Navigate (from any Screen) to Screen3 while needing parameter data from Screen2 (which uses StreamBuilder))

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Consider the following structure:

```
Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3
```

`Screen2` has a `StreamBuilder` connected to `Firestore` with a `ListView.builder` which shows a list of chats. If a user clicks on a chat, the respective group chat is opened. So `Screen2` gives a lot of parameters to `Screen3`, like groupId, groupName, groupImage, etc. to open the correct chat with all of its data.

I now want to navigate to a specific chat of `Screen3`, let's say the one for groupId 22233313 with a single click (yep, on a push notification). I have the groupId, but I first somehow need to get the data from `Screen2` (out of the `StreamBuilder`), otherwise I get a lot of null values.

Can I somehow open `Screen2`, automatically click on the chat with the respective groupId to go to Screen3 or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should not keep your FireStore data dependent on screens.
2. Make a repository class to hold your data.
3. When you receive data, pass it to your repository class.
4. While opening screen 3 pass only groupId from screen 2.
5. Access your data from repository with groupId.
6. Similar structure will work for you in case of notifications.

I recommend you to do this using BLoC pattern.

Comment: Any easier solution without changing my hole data structure?